# Get value of dynamically generated checkbox in form panel - windows application c#

Tags: c#

I am dynamically generating `Checkboxes` on `button` click which I am adding to a panel in `TableLayoutPanel`.

```
Panel panel1=new panel();
CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
box.Name = "cb_" + count;
box.AutoSize = true;
panel1.Controls.Add(box);
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1);
count++;
```

I need to check if these checkboxes are checked on Save button click. But when i try to retrieve the `Checkbox` it returns null. (But if I add the checkbox directly to the form instead of `TablelayoutPanel` I am able to retrieve it.)

```
for (int i = 0; i >= count; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb =  this.Controls["cb_" + i] as CheckBox;// Returns Null
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
       //Add code
    }
}
```

How can I get the checbox state?

Comment: It is because `this.Controls["cb_" + i]` returns null or is not of type `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the form controls and not in the tableLayoutPanel1

change the code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i >= count; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb =  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["cb_" + i] as CheckBox;
    if (cb.Checked)
        {
           //Add code
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to this:

```
foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
     CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
     if (cb!=null)
     {
          if (cb.Checked)
          {
               //Add code
          }
     }
}
```